# AWS Cognito list-user is broken

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

AWS Cognito seems to be broken (20/2/2018).

We had a user pool with users and the users list is now empty.

I replicated the issue creating a new user pool, and adding a user, yet the user list is empty.

[image]

Even the cli gives an empty list

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id <my-region>_<my_UP_ID>
{
    "Users": []
}
```

On the existing pool, it happened to be using groups, and there, the users are shown. With a curious detail, when linking on a user that was being accessed recently, the last activity is older than a month.
[image]

It is bound to be a problem, so logged into technical support already, will wait for an answer. In the meantime maybe someone can find workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS was broken and a whole working day does not fit the criteria to notify customers.

> On Tuesday afternoon 21/2/2017 AEDT we discovered an issue that led to
>   increased error rates with ListUsers API calls in Sydney region where
>   empty results were being returned for a limited number of customers.
>   At the time, it was still possible to search for users by specifying
>   Username or user attributes or filters such as Status or Enabled using
>   the same API. Apart from impacted functionality of ListUsers API used
>   for listing existing users, all other service functions were operating
>   as expected.
>
> The issue which was isolated to Sydney region and a limited number of
>   customers only, was resolved soon after being detected and the service
>   has been operating normally since. According to AWS management this
>   issue did not meet the criteria for an announcement in service health
>   dashboard and on behalf of AWS I apologize for any inconvenience this
>   may have caused in your environment.